# Why jQuery breaks on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create menu/navigation for mobile screen size. I have made variable that keeps track of is menu opened or not, and if it is then add class 'opened' to ul, but it only works 1st time, and then stops, but if I remove jQuery code that is adding class to ul, then it keeps working like it suppost to be, what might be the problem that causes click event to break?

```
Site.prototype.hamburgerHandler = function() {
  var site = this;
  $('#hamburger').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(!site.menuOpen) {
      $('nav ul').attr('class', 'open');
      site.menuOpen = true;
    } else {
      $('nav ul').attr('class', 'closed');
      site.menuOpen = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Code is also available here:
https://github.com/Kevin-Murda/SiteFichte/blob/c4122cdb6fb61a57adebc1b7f6863d8530b37ebd/pub/js/main.js#L144

Comment: Why not solve this problem using just CSS Media Queries?

Comment: Problem is that class will be applied only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, problem was caused by after menu is opened it will overlap hamburger button and however you see this button you are instead clicking menu and not the button, it all happened because I used padding-top instead of margin-top to position menu, it's solved now, thanks to everybody who helped.

Answer (score 2):

Use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. If this is a toggle you should be removing the class when it is clicked the second time.

Comment: There are different ways how to apply class, but it doesn't solve the problem that click event triggers only once.

Comment: Yeah but you aren't ever removing the open class. If you look at the DOM after the second click do you have both classes applied?

Comment: Because attr will remove everthing and will just apply value(class) that I specified.

Answer (score 2):

Updated

When you do `var site = this;` you get a reference to the element the handler is attached, as a locally scoped variable named `site`.

By dropping the line `var site = this`, the `site.menuOpen` will reference the globally defined `site`

---

As simpler solution would be to just toggle the `open` class, and no worries about setting any variable

```
Site.prototype.hamburgerHandler = function() {
  $('#hamburger').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('open');
  });
}
```

Comment: this.menuOpen is set to false on constructing, check it at: https://github.com/Kevin-Murda/SiteFichte/blob/c4122cdb6fb61a57adebc1b7f6863d8530b37ebd/pub/js/main.js#L9

Comment: @KevinMurda Since it is only used for that purpose, you don't need it, simply toggle the `open` class and adjust the CSS accordingly. Second, the `this` used in the handler is a reference to the hamburger element and is not same as the one used in `Site function`, so to continue to use that, drop the `var site = this;` in your original code

Comment: Tried your solution and it still won't close after i get this menu opened, and if you are telling me it's caused by scope, why does it work and keep track of menuOpen variable if I dont use jQuery functions?

Comment: @KevinMurda If you drop the `var site = this` line, what value does the `site.menuOpen` has when you enter first time and what when entered second time? ...  add `console.log(site.menuOpen)` to the code and check the dev.tools log

Comment: then its undefined, and will stay undefined due it will cause error,  variable site is made so I can reference Site obj beacause if I use this inside jquery function then will be not referencing Site obj.

Comment: It's really odd problem for that simple code, maybe clone repo and try it out yourself, if you comment out parts where you add class via jquery functions then it works. calling attr or classAdd will break click event.

Comment: @KevinMurda Why not go for the second option in my answer, much simpler and no need for a variable

Comment: I did try this, but It's not solving the problem, after I open it for 1st time, and click #hamburger icon again, it will never close, and class will be not removed.

Comment: @KevinMurda Then that sounds like the close button is different, and don't share same handler ... can it be that?

Comment: @KevinMurda As we don't see this in action, and can't spend time on clone a repro, you'll need to set this up for us, so we can test and see what's going on

Comment: I got this fixed, the reason why It never closed was that after i open menu, it will overlap hamburger button, and how ever I see the hamburger button I am really clicking the menu, I changed padding-top to margin-top and It solved the problem. And as your solution is cleaner than one I used, I will use your solution, thanks.

Comment: Of course, I'm using your solution now, I'm just kinda new in stackoverflow so I'm still learning how everything works in community and what actions users can perform, I been reading solutions all the time but never really asked or posted anything, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

menuOpen isn't defined, that's why it never traverses the loop.

Comment: And it does if you remove query parts from code, in class menuOpen is set to false on constructing the object.

Comment: What if you move this line "event.stopPropagation(" to terminate the event at the end of your else statement.

Comment: Still only works 1, removed it totally beacause it seems to be useless thing in this function.

Comment: Can you set menuOpen to true at the start? Maybe it matters?